# Webfaction setup Virtualenv

Tags: django, pip, virtualenv, webfaction

I've got to setup a new Django website on a webfaction account, getting issues when I try to run pip this is the error I get when I run
    pip install south

```
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/tmp/pip-build/virtualenv'
```

Answer (score 0):

Webfaction provides instructions on how to install pip and pip packages for use within your local home directory...
http://docs.webfaction.com/software/python.html#installing-packages-with-pip

If you plan on hosting multiple web applications from the same webfaction server, it's probably wise to setup virtualenvs for each application.  To do this, I would try the following...

1. pip install --user virtualenv   # install virtualenv via pip
2. echo 'export PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"' >> $HOME/.bashrc   # add local bin directory to PATH
3. source $HOME/.bashrc   # reload .bashrc to kick in PATH changes
4. virtualenv yourvirtualenv --no-site-packages

Hopefully that works.  I don't have Webfaction to test but I think that should suffice.

Comment: Problem is pip doesn't work and I need it to setup the virtualenv on the webfaction server. Any work around with `sudo` wouldn't work.

Comment: Alright, it looks like you are going to have to install pip locally to your home directory... http://docs.webfaction.com/software/python.html#installing-packages-with-pip  I'll update my answer with more relevant information.

Comment: Thanks but it seems somehow sudo won't give me access to these commands I get OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/tmp/pip-build/virtualenv'

Comment: Webfaction don't give you sudo / root permission.